# when usuing the php function, preg_match_all, how can i define where to start and stop?

Tags: php, regex

I am understanding that the function takes three parameters, and understand what they are..  but I can't figure out how to say - `Start here . take data . end here`.

Is this found in the regex?  Or am I way off?

Comment: Could you provide us your sample string? I have no idea what you are trying to say ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, where to start and stop parsing the data is a detail of the regular expression itself. You can control such processing using the character sets and repetition characters (i.e. + to match 1 or more occurrence, * for 0 or more occurrences etc) Additionally, you have the ^ character to specify the start of a line and the $ character to signify the end of the line.

Comment: is there a tool i can use for regex?

Answer (score 1):

The [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) takes two mandatory parameters and three optional ones.

If you want to start in a different position in the string, you can pass an `offset` (fifth parameter). If you want to end in a different position, I think you're stuck with a [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) call.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to say either but here goes.

You can use the ^ to say "Beginning of string" and $ to say "End of string". e.g

```
$match = preg_match("/^hello(.*)world$/", "hello this should match world", $matches);
```

This will match " this should match "

Does that help?

Comment: Would match everything, I think he wants to define a start point and end point somewhere within the string.